# mysql join two tables return the correct data ,but join three tables returns empty using java Statement executeQuery

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have three tables:

```
table req_specs(id int,testproject_id int,doc_id varchar) 

table requirements(id int,srs_id int,req_doc_id varchar)

tables nodes_hierarchy(id int,name varchar,parent_id int,node_type_id int,node_order int)
```

The first two table joining querying code

```
public String getRequirementDocIDofProject(String testprojectName)
        throws SQLException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException {
    String req_doc_id = "";
    initDB();
    resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from req_specs " + 
            "INNER JOIN requirements reqs " + 
            "on req_specs.id =reqs.srs_id where req_specs.testproject_id=7165 ");
    while (resultSet.next()) {
        req_doc_id = req_doc_id+" "+resultSet.getString("req_doc_id");
    }
    close();
    return req_doc_id;
}
```

`dbcon.getRequirementDocIDofProject("XXX");`returns correct data

The second three table joining querying code

```
public String getRequirementDocIDofProject(String testprojectName)
        throws SQLException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException {
    String req_doc_id = "";
    initDB();
    resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from req_specs INNER JOIN nodes_hierarchy nh " + 
            "on nh.id=req_specs.testproject_id  " + 
            "INNER JOIN requirements reqs " + 
            "on req_specs.id =reqs.srs_id where nh.name='"+testprojectName+"'   ");
    while (resultSet.next()) {
        req_doc_id = req_doc_id+" "+resultSet.getString("req_doc_id");
    }
    close();
    return req_doc_id;
}
```

`dbcon.getRequirementDocIDofProject("XXX");` returns empty.

but when I put the mysql in navicat ,it display the correct values

```
select * from req_specs INNER JOIN nodes_hierarchy nh
on nh.id=req_specs.testproject_id
INNER JOIN requirements reqs 
on req_specs.id =reqs.srs_id where nh.name='XXX'
```

Comment: Please post the stacktrace

Comment: @ScaryWombat , three table joining didn't return error stacktrace,it just return empty value.

Comment: make sure that `testprojectName` does not have some trailing spaces

Comment: @ScaryWombat ,yes.When I use  resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from req_specs INNER JOIN nodes_hierarchy nh on nh.id=req_specs.testproject_id  INNER JOIN requirements reqs on req_specs.id =reqs.srs_id where nh.name='DT'   "); It still return empty value

Comment: well if the sql is the same then either the login or the db is different

Comment: How many rows do you have in database?

Comment: or `req_doc_id` is empty... try some other column, just for testing

Comment: String testprojectName 's value is none English characters..I shall specify the right characters encoding

Comment: *dbcon.getRequirementDocIDofProject("XXX"); returns empty.* - so not true eh?

Answer (score -1):

I find the answer,in code

```
 "on req_specs.id =reqs.srs_id where nh.name='"+testprojectName+"'   ");
```

the field nh.name value is none English characters .I shall specify the right characters encoding .

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8","username", "password");
```